# C# Outlook message/folder creation and delay

Tags: c#, outlook, office-interop

I have simple application which saves programmatically folders and emails in local Outlook application. Code works fine but I observed that I have to add sleep when folder or message has been created otherwise some folders and messages are randomly missing.

This is my code:

```
public class EmailBoxToOutlookAppExporter : IEmailBoxExporter
{
    private IList<EmaillBox> _emailBoxes;

    private Application _outlookApplication;

    private NameSpace _nameSpace;

    private bool _killOutlookProcesWhenFinished;

    private string PR_MESSAGE_DELIVERY_TIME = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E060040";

    private string _exchangeUserName;

    private string _imapUserName;

    public EmailBoxToOutlookAppExporter(IList<EmaillBox> emailBoxes, string exchangeUserName, string imapUserName)
    {
        _emailBoxes = emailBoxes;
        _exchangeUserName = exchangeUserName;
        _imapUserName = imapUserName;
    }

    public void Export()
    {
        _outlookApplication = getOutlookApplication();

        _nameSpace = _outlookApplication.GetNamespace("MAPI");

        if(_emailBoxes != null && _emailBoxes.Count > 0)
        {
            int nbOfMessagesToProcess = _emailBoxes.Sum(e => e.EmailMessages.Count);
            int nbOfMessagesProcessed = 0;

            foreach(EmaillBox emailBox in _emailBoxes)
            {
                MAPIFolder folderInfo = createMailBoxFolder(emailBox);
                waitForOutlookItem();

                if (emailBox.EmailMessages != null && emailBox.EmailMessages.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (EmailMessage emailMessage in emailBox.EmailMessages)
                    {
                        createEmailMessage(emailMessage, folderInfo);

                        waitForOutlookItem();
                        createContacts(emailMessage);
                        waitForOutlookItem();
                        nbOfMessagesProcessed++;

                        ProcessProgress.SetProgress(KnownProcessName.ExportEmailBoxesToLocalOutlookApp, nbOfMessagesProcessed, nbOfMessagesToProcess);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //add logging...
                }
                //Marshal.ReleaseComObject(folderInfo);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ProcessProgress.SetProgress(KnownProcessName.ExportEmailBoxesToLocalOutlookApp, 0, 0);
        }

        if (_killOutlookProcesWhenFinished)
        {
            killOutlookApplicationProcess();
            startOutlookApplicationProcess();
        }
    }

    private MAPIFolder createMailBoxFolder(EmaillBox emailBox)
    {
        MAPIFolder mapiFolder = findMailBoxRootFolder();

        IList<string> splittedEmailBoxPath = emailBox.Name.Split('/');

        foreach (string emailBoxPathPart in splittedEmailBoxPath)
        {
            MAPIFolder nextMapiFolder = findSubFolder(mapiFolder, emailBoxPathPart);
            if (nextMapiFolder == null)
            {
                mapiFolder = addNewSubFolder(mapiFolder, emailBoxPathPart);
            }
            else
                mapiFolder = nextMapiFolder;
        }

        return mapiFolder;
    }

    private MAPIFolder findMailBoxRootFolder()
    {
        Store selectedStore = null;

        foreach(Store store in _nameSpace.Session.Stores)
        {
            if(store.DisplayName.ToUpper() == _exchangeUserName.ToUpper())
            {
                selectedStore = store;
            }
        }

        if (selectedStore == null)
            selectedStore = _nameSpace.Session.DefaultStore;

        MAPIFolder rootFolder = selectedStore.GetRootFolder();
        
        MAPIFolder imapUserNameFolder = findSubFolder(rootFolder, _imapUserName);
        if (imapUserNameFolder == null)
        {
            rootFolder = addNewSubFolder(rootFolder, _imapUserName);
            waitForOutlookItem();
        }
        else
            rootFolder = imapUserNameFolder;
        
        return rootFolder;
    }

    private MAPIFolder findSubFolder(MAPIFolder parentFolderId, string folderName)
    {
        MAPIFolder mAPIFolder = null;

        foreach (MAPIFolder subFolder in parentFolderId.Folders)
        {
            if(subFolder.Name.ToUpper() == folderName.ToUpper())
            {
                mAPIFolder = subFolder;
                break;
            }
        }

        return mAPIFolder;
    }

    private MAPIFolder addNewSubFolder(MAPIFolder parentMapiFolder, string folderName)
    {
        MAPIFolder newFolder = parentMapiFolder.Folders.Add(folderName);
        return newFolder;
    }

    private MailItem createEmailMessage(EmailMessage emailMessage, MAPIFolder mapiFolder)
    {
        MailItem mailItem = null;

        if(emailMessage != null && mapiFolder != null)
        {
            mailItem = (MailItem)_outlookApplication.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem);

            mailItem.UnRead = false;
            mailItem.Subject = emailMessage.Subject;
            mailItem.Body = emailMessage.Body;
            mailItem.To = getPeoplesList(emailMessage.To);
            mailItem.CC = getPeoplesList(emailMessage.Cc);
            mailItem.BCC = getPeoplesList(emailMessage.Bcc);
            mailItem.SentOnBehalfOfName = emailMessage.From?.EmailAddress;

            PropertyAccessor propertyAccessor = mailItem.PropertyAccessor;
            propertyAccessor.SetProperty(PR_MESSAGE_DELIVERY_TIME, emailMessage.Date);

            if (emailMessage.Attachments != null && emailMessage.Attachments.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (Model.Attachment attachment in emailMessage.Attachments)
                    createAttachment(attachment, mailItem);
            }

            mailItem.Move(mapiFolder);
        }

        return mailItem;
    }

    private void createContacts(EmailMessage emailMessage)
    {
        createContact(emailMessage.From);
        
        foreach (Person person in emailMessage.To)
            createContact(person);

        foreach (Person person in emailMessage.Cc)
            createContact(person);

        foreach (Person person in emailMessage.Bcc)
            createContact(person);
    }

    private ContactItem createContact(Person person)
    {
        ContactItem contactItem = null;

        if(person != null)
        {
            MAPIFolder contactsFolder = _outlookApplication.Session.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts);

            if(contactsFolder != null && contactsFolder.Items != null && contactsFolder.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (ContactItem existingContactItem in contactsFolder.Items)
                {
                    if (existingContactItem.Email1Address == person.EmailAddress)
                    {
                        contactItem = existingContactItem;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            
            if (contactItem == null)
            {
                contactItem = _outlookApplication.CreateItem(OlItemType.olContactItem) as ContactItem;
                contactItem.Email1Address = person.EmailAddress;
                contactItem.FullName = person.DisplayName;
                contactItem.Save();
            }
        }

        return contactItem;
    }

    private string getPeoplesList(IList<Person> peoples)
    {
        string peoplesList = string.Empty;

        if (peoples != null && peoples.Count > 0)
            peoplesList = string.Join(";", peoples.Select(p => p.EmailAddress));

        return peoplesList;
    }

    private void createAttachment(Model.Attachment attachment, MailItem mailItem)
    {
        if(attachment != null && mailItem != null)
        {
            string filePath = Path.Combine(ApplicationSettings.RootFolder, attachment.FileName);

            byte[] attachmentBytes;

            if (attachment.ContentTransferEncoding != null)
                attachmentBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(attachment.Content);
            else
                attachmentBytes = attachment.Encoding.GetBytes(attachment.Content);

            File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, attachmentBytes);

            mailItem.Attachments.Add(filePath);

            File.Delete(filePath);
        }
    }

    private Application getOutlookApplication()
    {
        Application outlookApplication = null;

        try
        {
            outlookApplication = Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application") as Application;
        }
        catch
        {
            //add logging...
        }

        if (outlookApplication == null)
        {
            outlookApplication = new Application();

            _killOutlookProcesWhenFinished = true;
        }

        return outlookApplication;
    }

    private void killOutlookApplicationProcess()
    {
        Process outlookApplicationProcess = Process.GetProcesses().
                                            FirstOrDefault(pr => pr.ProcessName.ToUpper() == "OUTLOOK");

        if(outlookApplicationProcess != null)
        {
            outlookApplicationProcess.Kill();
        }
    }

    private void startOutlookApplicationProcess()
    {
        Process.Start("OUTLOOK");
    }

    private void waitForOutlookItem()
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(700);
    }

}
```

So my question is: how to deal with waitForOutlookItem() method and make this code work without hardcoded sleep?

Thank you in advance!